# Chrome twitter plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, twitter

Is there any twitter plugin for Google Chrome which is similar to Echofon for Firefox? I think, this is the only reason of using firefox instead of chrome - suitable twitter client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Silver Bird](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/encaiiljifbdbjlphpgpiimidegddhic) is one of the most popular (some think it's the best)

The features aren't identical to Echofon, but it has some features Echofon doesn't.  It get's 4.5 star ratings...

Comment: it's superb. i like it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there's always [TweetDeck](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hbdpomandigafcibbmofojjchbcdagbl), which offers a lot more featurewise and looks gorgeous. However, it doesn't look like Echofon.

Answer (score 1):

[Hotot](http://hotot.org) has got a Google Chrome version too.